# Implementing the derivation of the Smith Shadowing function for arbitrary distributions

Tags: opengl, c++, microfacet, masking

I'm trying to implement the derivation of the masking function G_1 by Smith.
The appendix of Walter et al [1](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~srm/publications/EGSR07-btdf.pdf), Hammons presentation [2](https://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc2017/Presentations/Hammon_Earl_PBR_Diffuse_Lighting.pdf) and this research paper [3](https://docs.chaosgroup.com/display/RESEARCH/Deriving+the+Smith+shadowing+function+for+the+GTR+BRDF) talk in detail about it and I feel as I do understand the majority of the math behind it. But when it comes to turning this into code I cannot seem to get it right.

Some of my questions entail:

In the first integral from minus infinity to infinity over *P22(p, q)*, the way I understand it I can simply iterate over all of my microfacets and use the previous formular (*P22(p, q) = D(**m**) cos^4(theta_m)*) and add them together for a riemann sum?

As far as I understand is mu (*= |cot(theta_v)|*) the slope of the view vector and when using an integral from mu to infinity the goal is to decrease te angle of theta_v until it is zero?

The way I naivly implemented it is as an nested loop of two riemann sums that aim to describe the two integrals. In pseudocode:

```
calculate mu from view angle
Aux = 0.0;
//for loop uses calculation of the angle theta_v to decide termination of loop
for(float q = mu; angleof(q) > 0.0001f; q += dq)
{
   float P2 = 0.0;
   for(iterate through all maicrofacets)
   {
      calulate theta of current microfacet
      calculate cos^4(theta)
      get D of current microfacet

      P2 += D * cos^4(theta) * dp;
   }
   Aux += (q - mu) * P2 * dq;
}

Aux *= 1.0 / mu;
return 1.0 / (1.0 + Aux)
```

I write in C++ but I would be very happy with any kind of code or hint as to how to solve this.